# How may I load the points/restore the points to display a signature?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Using [Xamarin Signature Pad](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad) Xamarin.Forms code and examples, I've developed the following.

Using Json I serialize the signature `Point[]` array and store it in the database. When the user selects a list item, the signature data `Point[]` string is pulled from the database and deserialized and stored in a `Point[]`. I see that the Xamarin Signature Pad documentation says I may load a signature by the following `signature.LoadPoints (points);` line.

I tried doing this in the ItemView code after creating padView with no success.

How may I load the points/restore the points to display a signature?

ListView code:

```
async void OnListItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((App)App.Current).ResumeAtDatabaseId = (e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem).ID;
    Debug.WriteLine("setting ResumeAtDatabaseId = " + (e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem).ID);

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DatabaseItemView
    {
        //BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem
        Name = (e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem).Name,
        Date = Convert.ToDateTime((e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem).Date),
        PadViewPointsString = (e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem).SignatureData
});
}
```

ItemView code:

```
public partial class DatabaseItemView : ContentPage
    {
        public string Name { get => Name.Text; set => Name.Text = value; }
        public DateTime Date { get => Date.Date; set => Date.Date = value; }
        public SignaturePadView PadView { get => padView; set => padView = value; }
        public string PadViewPointsString
        {
            get => padViewPointsString;
            set
            {
                padViewPointsString = value;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    PadViewPoints = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Xamarin.Forms.Point[]>(value);
                }
            }
        }
        public Xamarin.Forms.Point[] PadViewPoints { get => padViewPoints; set => padViewPoints = value; }

        private Entry Name;
        private DatePicker Date;
        private SignaturePadView padView;
        private IEnumerable<Point> signatureData;
        private string padViewPointsString;
        private Point[] padViewPoints;

        public DatabaseItemView ()
        {
            //InitializeComponent ();

            //Name
            Name = new Entry
            {
                Placeholder = "Name"
            };
            //Name.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Name");            

            //Date
            Date = new DatePicker
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.Date
            };
            //Date.SetBinding(DatePicker.DateProperty, "Date");

            //signature
            padView = new SignaturePadView
            {
                HeightRequest = 150, WidthRequest = 240,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                CaptionText = "Caption This", CaptionTextColor = Color.Black,
                ClearText = "Clear Me!", ClearTextColor = Color.Red,
                PromptText = "Prompt Here", PromptTextColor = Color.Red,
                SignatureLineColor = Color.Aqua, StrokeColor = Color.Black, StrokeWidth = 2
            };

            //signatureData

            //saveButton
            var saveButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Save",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large),
                //Command = new Command(() => App.NavigateTo<DatabaseItemViewModel>()),
            };
            saveButton.Clicked += OnSaveButtonClicked;

            //build the page
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Spacing = 20,
                Padding = 50,
                //VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children =
                {
                    Name,
                    Date,
                    padView,
                    saveButton
                }
            };
        }

        async void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var temp = padView.Points;
            var tempArray = padView.Points.ToArray();
            //serialize tempArray to json and store as text
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempArray);

            var databaseItem = new DatabaseItem
            {
                ID = ((App)App.Current).ResumeAtDatabaseId,
                Name = Name.Text,
                Date = Date.Date.ToString(),
                SignatureData = json
            };
            //var databaseItem = (DatabaseItem)BindingContext;
            await App.Database.SaveItemAsync(databaseItem);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the fact that the constructor executes before the properties are set. Try to add this line in the end of PadViewPointsString **setter** (after setting PadViewPoints): `padView.LoadPoints(PadViewPoints);`

Comment: I tried that. The `SignaturePadView` class doesn't contain a definition for LoadPoints. I also tried adding `padView.Points = PadViewPoints;` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Well, if you look at line 81 of the source code of this view [source](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/blob/e931fa9f742c0904780c364c5d667d062d1fbdac/src/SignaturePad.Forms.Shared/SignaturePadView.cs#L81), the correct way of doing what you want is `padView.Points = PadViewPoints`, but without knowing what exception is thrown when you try to do that, I can't help much. So can you add the exception thrown when this line is executed (**at PadViewPointsString setter**)?

Comment: There's no exception being thrown.

Comment: So, did you check that the Points are correctly deserializing? Did you see what was it's value before calling `padView.Points = PadViewPoints`?

Comment: I did. So this may be helpful or it may be weird -> I created a button and created a method `private async void OnButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e)` inside method I have `padView.Points = PadViewPoints;` and it loads the signature as expected when the button is clicked. I'm not sure why this works and the other method doesn't. I don't want to rely on a button click to load the signature.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that the view only sets the Points after it has been rendered. Try to add a SizeChanged handler in the constructor, and in it, change the Points property. e.g. `SizeChanged += (sender, e) => { 
if(padView.Points == null) padView.Points = PadViewPoints; };`